# Xamarin Forms: How to change the background color when playing audio in Plugin.MediaManager.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, plugin.mediamanager.forms

I am using `Plugin.MediaManager.Forms` for playing a list of audios. I am also showing the same list of items (text data) in a listview. **When playing audio I need to change the background color of the item.**

**My Code:**

```
List<string> songsUrlList = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < chaptersList.Count; i++)
{
    songsUrlList.Add(aduioFormat+ chaptersList[i].audioUrl);
}
var mediaItem = await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(songsUrlList);
```

**First I created an audio list, then I play that list like above. I am able to change the background color of the first item. When the remaining audio starts playing I don't know how to change the background color.**

If I tap an item, I clear the `songsUrlList` first, then create a new list and play that list like below. Is it a correct implementation?

```
private async void ChapterTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (ListVerses)e.Item;
    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Pause();
        songsUrlList.Clear();
        for (int i = Int32.Parse(selectedItem.slno) - 1; i < chaptersList.Count; i++)
        {
            songsUrlList.Add(aduioFormat+ chaptersList[i].audioUrl);
        }
        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(songsUrlList);
        audioOrder = Int32.Parse(selectedItem.slno) - 1;
        selectedItem.BGColor = Color.FromHex("#f2ee71");
    }
    ChapterList.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

**I need to change the background color of the list item when audio plays that item.** I have added an expected feature video [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14iGg3Ubs2zbcFPLjvfPssFNH1vbC6PkN/view?usp=sharing).

I have added a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QX5iQEMP0ecaAg6ZV6Ui5RNSUKMKX9Wd/view?usp=sharing) for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the event **MediaItemFinished**

```
 CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaItemFinished += Current_MediaItemFinished;
```

```
private void Current_MediaItemFinished(object sender, MediaManager.Media.MediaItemEventArgs e)
    {
        audioOrder = audioOrder + 1;
        if (audioOrder < chaptersList.Count)
        {
            MyVidem.Source = aduioFormat + chaptersList[audioOrder].audioUrl;
            ChapterList.ItemsSource = chaptersList;
            chaptersList[audioOrder].BGColor = Color.FromHex("#f2ee71");
            ChapterList.ScrollTo(((IList)ChapterList.ItemsSource)[audioOrder - 1], ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
        }
    }
```